# 解像度を保ったままフルスクリーンで表示する

Tags: unity3d, unity2d

[マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/102083?modal=q-comp)
Unityで解像度800×600のゲームを作っています。
現在フルスクリーンに対応するため色々やっているのですが，どうしても画像が横に伸びてしまいます。
解像度は保ったまま，余分な部分は黒帯を入れたいです。
どうすれば，比率を保ったままフルスクリーンで表示できるでしょうか？

以下のURLを参考にしたのですが，やはり画像が伸びます。
http://tsubakit1.hateblo.jp/entry/2014/12/24/233000
Screen.SetResolution(800, 600, true);
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下はCanvasの設定です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

テスト環境はこちらです。
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11RwuILr_rV0VttWp1pwJzEneOK8Nk0bk

Comment: 門外漢なので回答は出来ませんが、アスペクト比を固定にしたいということだと思いましたので、こちらの記事は参考になりませんでしょうか。 https://qiita.com/kwst/items/371542a6d3892b577b41

Comment: ありがとうございます。画面横に縁は出ますが，画像は伸びたままです。

Comment: WindowsならSetResolutionで比率を保ったままフルスクリーンにすることができました